# Resize images with paperclip with amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip gem for uploading images to s3 amazone. Three copy of images are uploading - one is real and two are of different resolution like 10x10,50x50.

Now I want to upload 5 copy of images like 10x10, 20x20 ,......
This can be done by specifying size in model.

But what about the existing images on s3. How to create copy of existing images on s3 ?

Comment: what? where? when? with what?

Comment: Hi Nick Ginanto, Please check updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the style in the model

```
styles => { :first=> "10x10", :second=> "20x20", :third=> "30x30", ....},
```

and after you made your new styles just use the rake task paperclip provides

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User
```

where User is the model in this case

This will go on every user and regenerate the images

see more here
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation